# How to print unicode json using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, unicode

I try to print JSON response in my html document so I do:

```
respdiv.innerHTML = '<pre><code>' + xhr.responseText + '</code></pre>';
```

The problem is my response is printed like this :

```
{ "error": "Sc\\u00e9nario invalide" }
```

I want my response to be printed like this :

```
{ "error": "Scénario invalide" }
```

How I get this?

Comment: It sounds like you need to fix the problem on the server. Can you make the server return the response in UTF-8 or not escape the \ characer?

Comment: I will try to figure out how to do it in the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delegate all the work to `JSON.parse()` then `unescape` the characters:

```
var responseText = unescape(JSON.parse('"' + xhr.responseText + '"'));
respdiv.innerHTML = '<pre><code>' + responseText + '</code></pre>';
```

*But as @p.s.w.g suggested, I would advice fixing it on server side.*

Comment: Your code is not working but I managed to get the result using your idea. Thanks!

Comment: You can provide the snippet that made it work in order to help future readers, think community :)

Comment: I changed the code provided in the answer but not accepcted

Comment: Sure it won't work on the provided fiddle with my hook just because you are trying to parse a JSON object ({ "error": "Sc\\u00e9nario invalide" }) while I wrote a snippet to only unescape a straightforward string object. You got it?
Take a look at this version of you fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/fsh6s/1/ and compare it to yours. You will see the difference.